# Trying to add a click event to an image with JQuery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have an image without an ID. The only unique identifiers are src and alt. Not sure what I'm doing wrong with the below but I've been chasing my tail for a while now.

```html
<img class="imageTile_overlay__DQMRS imageTile_no-stretch__3GYzr" src="/_web/assets/applications/c21140ec-719d-4fe8-aa34-381144127302/c503ca4f-1a36-49df-ae90-75a9226e7e69?X-IoT-Region=westus" alt="fire">

<script>
$('img[alt="fire"]').click(function() {
  alert('clicked');
}); 
</script>
```

I'm trying to do this in a Chrome browser extension. I've tried it within window.onload and now document.ready. Still clicking does nothing.

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser dev-tools console? Have you included jQuery in the page prior to the above `<script>` tag?

Comment: Please answer @Phil's initial questions below your post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That code works.

Include it between:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img[alt="fire"]').click(function() {
        alert('clicked');
    }); 

});
    </script>
```

Comment: OP already had the `<script>` tag after the `<img>` element so does not require a _ready_ handler

Comment: @Phil I added document ready.

Comment: Yes, I know. What I'm saying is that it is not required

Comment: Hmm. I'm trying to do this in a Chrome browser extension. I've tried it within window.onload and now document.ready. Still clicking does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the onload event is triggered before the page's app logic starts. So the page actually waits for my extension to complete before continuing so the image doesn't exist yet.